# A bug in Scalatest 'DoubleTolerance'?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I've encountered failing tests which in all of my understanding should pass. Am I missing something obvious, here?

```
import org.scalatest._

class xxxTests extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers {
  import math.{Pi => PI}

  "" should "(this should pass)" in {
    assert( 0.0 === 0.0 )  // ok

    (1e-100) should equal ((0.0) plusOrMinus 1e-5)    // FAILS!!!  "1.0E-100 did not equal DoubleTolerance(0.0,1.0E-5)"
    (1e-3) should not equal ((0.0) plusOrMinus 1e-5)    // ok
    (0.0) should equal ((0.0) plusOrMinus 1e-5)    // FAILS!!!  "0.0 did not equal DoubleTolerance(0.0,1.0E-5)"
  }
}
```

I've experienced this with both Scalatest 1.8 and 2.0M4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem: must use `be`, not `equal`.

Leaving here as a sign of my stupidity (ehem, lack of focus).

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/scalatest-users/pb54GzOej6I/C9714h_OW_UJ

> You must use plusOrMinus with "be" not "equal". "equal" always
>   compares for equality by invoking == on one object, passing in the
>   other. "be" does different things depending on what object is being
>   passed. So try:
>
> 0.5 must be (0.5 plusOrMinus 0.1)

Comment: Well, don't be too hard on yourself. I think the DSL invites this mistake. My original idea was that matchers needed some way that always means calling == on two objects, and that's what equal does. Except it does call .deep on an Array on the left and right, so that's an exception. I think "x should equal (y plusOrMinus tol)" looks like it should work, and I've seen more than one user try it now. So I think I'll actually support that syntax in a coming soon version of ScalaTest. If someone really ever wants to compare two tolerances for equality, they could do so with an assertion.